# CSS rule like inline-block to match exactly the space the text takes

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

If I do

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">Some text</div>
```

The div dimension fits closely the rectangle the text fits in, but not exactly:
[image]

More precisely, it fits perfectly horizontally, but not vertically. And the height will be the same wether the text is "A", "..." or "ppp", while the space used by the text changes. Is there a css property that would behave like inline block, but treat the text as a more floating element and have the smallest height that can contain the current text? Like (photoshoped):

[image]

Comment: Simply...No...there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

To make that happen, and since every font has its own inner white space and renders different on different browsers, you need to measure a particular font's size and "cut" of the rest.

One way could be cloning the element and draw it on a canvas and the count colored pixels from top/bottom to get its exact height.

---

*Further reading about fonts: [http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/_)*